# Go regex to capture the first occurence with special character

Tags: regex, go

If given `(TEXT)testest (GOPHER)mytest (TAG)(not_this)`,

I want to grep only the first occurrence of characters inside parentheses.

The regex results need to be `TEXT`, `GOPHER`, `TAG`, but NOT `not_this` because this is not the first occurrence in that word phrase. And the grepped text should be only letters not numbers.

```
regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)\([a-z0-9_-])+\]`)
// is not working
```

How do I write the regular expression to grep this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Should that be `\)` at the end?

Comment: So you want the first occurrence of parenthesized text? `\([a-zA-Z]+\)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [regex](http://regexr.com/3a350) you are looking for is:

```
(?:^|\W)\(([\w-]+)\)
```

**Meaning:**

```
(?:^|\W) /* find but discard the sequence-start or a non-word character */

\(CONTENTS\) /* Contained in () */

(CONTENTS) /* Selection Group */

[\w-]+ /* word character or -, once or more */
```